# ! Package amsmath Error: \begin{split} won't work here

Tags: equations, amsmath, texmaker, split

I tried to run following code in texmaker,

```
\begin{equation} \label{eq4}  
\begin{split}  
&R^T \left( \underbar r_{H/G} \times \underline f_H + \underline r_{R/G} \times \underline f_R + \underline \tau_R \right) \\  
 &= I_G \underline \alpha + \underline \omega \times \left( I_G \underline \omega \right)  
\end{split}  
\end{equation}
```

and got following error message,

`! Package amsmath Error: \begin{split} won't work here.`

What caused this problem and how can I fix it?

Of course, this is part of a document. Therefore, \begin{document} and \end{document} exist at the beginning and the end of the document.

Edited:

@daleif

```
\documentclass[fleqn,10pt,twocolumn]{ICCAS2020}

\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage {subfigure}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage {amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\section{EX}

\begin{equation} \label{eq4}
\begin{split}
&R^T \left( \underbar r_{H/G} \times \underline f_H + \underline r_{R/G} \times \underline f_R + \underline \tau_R \right) \\
 &= I_G \underline \alpha + \underline \omega \times \left( I_G \underline \omega \right)
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Is this what you mean?

@Sebastiano

Thanks for your kind welcome, but your code didn't work for me.

By the way, what does MWE mean?

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE. What are your package, please?

Comment: Since this compiles just fine for me, we need you to provide (as it tradition on this site) a full (but minimal) example that demonstrates the problem. Thus a document with document class, minimal preamble, that others can copy and test as is.

Comment: Thank you very much for your collaboration. Meanwhile delete the blank spaces in `\usepackage {amsmath}` and in the `\usepackage {subfigure}`.

Comment: Where is `ICCAS2020.cls` it is not a known class.

Comment: @daleif that is a name of a conference where I try to submit my paper.

Comment: And where do the rest of us get access to it. As you can see from Sebastianos answer there is no issues with the MWE (minimal working example) when we use the article class. So either we need the class it self, or the compilation log (the log file from disk not the filtered version from texmaker) of the exact example you posted here. We can see a lot of information from this log.

Comment: @daleif you can get the template from this link: http://2020.iccas.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/ICCAS2020.zip

Comment: You can remove all the packages from the MWE and still have the same error (the class autoloads `amsmath`)

Comment: @daleif Thank you very very much for your contribute.

Answer (score 4):

Remove the `fleqn` option. The class you use essentially do something like this when the `fleqn` option is active

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\input{fleqn.clo}
```

So if we try

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\input{fleqn.clo}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{equation} \label{eq4}
\begin{split}
&R^T \left( \underbar r_{H/G} \times \underline f_H + \underline r_{R/G} \times \underline f_R + \underline \tau_R \right) \\
 &= I_G \underline \alpha + \underline \omega \times \left( I_G \underline \omega \right)
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

we get the same error, which goes away if the `\input` line is removed.

I'd recommend writing to the organisers and showing them your example.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers.

Answer (score 2):

Just your code compile fine for me...I have deleted `amsmath` and I have leaved the robust command `mathtools`.

```
\documentclass[fleqn,10pt,twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\section{EX}

\begin{equation} \label{eq4}
\begin{split}
&R^T \left( \underbar r_{H/G} \times \underline f_H + \underline r_{R/G} \times \underline f_R + \underline \tau_R \right) \\
 &= I_G \underline \alpha + \underline \omega \times \left( I_G \underline \omega \right)
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your code worked fine, thanks! It seems ICCAS2020 make the problem...